# react-bootstrap NavBar trouble

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am new to ReactJS and having trouble using react-bootstrap navbar. I could use guidance as there's little or no information on this.

when I add the navbar code directly inside index.js and render it there, it work but i want to use component for every feature.

//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('App'));
```

//App.js

```
import '../public/App.css';
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar';
import Appintro from './components/Appintro';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <NavigationBar />
        <Appintro />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

// NavBar component[ this doesnt work]

```
let React , {Component} = require('react')
let Navbar = require("react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar");
let NavItem = require("react-bootstrap/lib/NavItem");
let Nav = require ("react-bootstrap/lib/Nav");


class NavigationBar extends Component {

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        const appNavbar = (
        <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
           <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">Company-x</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav pullRight>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">home</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">about</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">products</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">services</NavItem>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    )
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

// intro

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import headeeer from '../images/headeeer.jpg'; 
let Jumbotron = require ("react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron");

class Appintro extends Component {

  render() {
     Jumbotron=(
       <h1>Hello world, I am react-bootstrap jumbotron</h1>
       )
    return (
    <div>
      {Jumbotron}
      <img src={headeeer} className='imagesss' alt='jhe' />

    </div>

    );
  }
}
export default Appintro;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your react code is invalid. See below for the correct way to do this.

```html
let React , {Component} = require('react')
let Navbar = require("react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar");
let NavItem = require("react-bootstrap/lib/NavItem");
let Nav = require ("react-bootstrap/lib/Nav");


class NavigationBar extends Component {

render() {

        const appNavbar = (
        <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
           <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">Company-x</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav pullRight>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">home</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">about</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">products</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">services</NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        );

    return (
    <div>
      {appNavbar}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

Comment: Hi @anthony I have tried that see error [class NavigationBar extends Component {
> 10 |      const appNavbar = (
     |            ^
  11 |         <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
  12 |            <Navbar.Header>
  13 |             <Navbar.Brand>

Comment: Please I still need your help on this.

Comment: I just corrected your syntax, I have no context for this component and none of the dependancies would be pulled in so I wouldnt expect it to work when you click the 'Run code snippet' button.
I apologise, my initial reply was incorrect, I've corrected it and made a working example of the correct syntax, as illustrated here:
https://codepen.io/c0un7z3r0/pen/zNQoey